# How to get ImageView scale to fill the layout as much as the width permits

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

What I want is for the ImageView to scale with the same ratio to fill the layout without being cropped. Since the width is going to match first, effectively, this means scaling until the width is maximized.

My code is:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_display);
    ImageView img = findViewById(R.id.displayImg);
    img.setImageBitmap(bmp); // bmp is a public static Bitmap set by another class
    img.setRotation(90);
    img.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
}
```

My layout is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

   <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/displayImg" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

As per [Android ImageView ScaleType: A Visual Guide](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/android-imageview-scaletype-a-visual-guide) `CENTER_INSIDE` should

> Scale the image uniformly (maintain the image’s aspect ratio) so that both dimensions (width and height) of the image will be equal to or less than the corresponding dimension of the view (minus padding).

The black image is what I'm currently, and I've drawn what I believe I *should* be seeing instead (as you can tell, I'm the modern-day Michelangelo).
[image]

Comment: If your image isnt as big as the view you are putting it in its only going to  show the size it is with `wrap_content`. And if the image is smaller than the size of the screen and you set the image to `match_parent` its going to be blurry and/or scaled weird depending on rotation

Comment: Downvoters, explain.

Answer (score 3):

Add these two lines to your ImageView:

android:scaleType="fitXY"

android:adjustViewBounds="true"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

   <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:id="@+id/displayImg" />
```

Answer (score 1):

wrap_content if the reason why.... change that to fill_parent or match_parent.

Take a look at this:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html

> CENTER_INSIDE Scale the image uniformly (maintain the image's aspect
>   ratio) so that both dimensions (width and height) of the image will be
>   equal to or less than the corresponding dimension of the view (minus
>   padding).

If the ratio of your image is off, it wont stretch.

Java

```
imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
```

XML

```
android:scaleType="fitCenter"
```

side note: fillXY might be better.

Comment: All this does is center the image.

Comment: use fitXY. If it stretches it, you need to supply a larger image. you can make the image for all devices by taking advantage of the hdpi, mdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi, xxxhdpi

Answer (score 0):

You may acheive your desired result by making the dimensions of the ImageView match to the parent layout and apply fitCenter as a scaleType so it fills the view without losing aspect ratio:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
   <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:id="@+id/displayImg" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Doesn't work. The image is the same, except moved to the center.

Comment: @K_7 . thanks for letting me know,  I've updated my answer to include scaleType so the image will fill the view but not lose its aspect ratio.

Comment: I'm not an android expert but from all I've read about constraint layout, you shouldn't use `match_parent`, instead use `0dp`

Answer (score 0):

I think you use wrong value. Try `android:scaleType="fitXY"` on xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

   <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/displayImg"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

You don't need set again scaleType on activity.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_display);
    ImageView img = findViewById(R.id.displayImg);
    img.setImageBitmap(bmp); // bmp is a public static Bitmap set by another class
    img.setRotation(90);
    //img.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY); You don't need this 
}
```

Comment: This just stretches the width; not what I'm looking for.

Comment: You can't do it without dissolution. Image have a resolution and if you want to with to fit bigger resolution of screen it will be stretch. Maybe you can prepare your images for [multiple resolution](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html).